# EF Core. Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Book' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Now I'm working on migration existing project from net framework to net core. As soon as it looked working, I ran into a strange exception. All the places pass '-1' value for db entity PK, but it doesn't work with ef core. Below two simple tests for reproducing.

```
    // EF core test
    [Test] // failed
    public void Test1()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConsoleApp1.Context>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Data")
            .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
            .Options;

        var context = new ConsoleApp1.Context(options);
        context.Books.Add(new ConsoleApp1.Book { Id = -1 });
        context.Books.Add(new ConsoleApp1.Book { Id = 0 });
        context.Books.Add(new ConsoleApp1.Book { Id = -1 });

        Assert.Pass();
    }

    // EF 6 test
    [Test] // passed
    public void Test2()
    {
        var context = new ConsoleApp2.Context();
        context.Books.Add(new ConsoleApp2.Book { Id = -1 });
        context.Books.Add(new ConsoleApp2.Book { Id = 0 });
        context.Books.Add(new ConsoleApp2.Book { Id = -1 });

        Assert.Pass();
    }
```

I've tried many workarounds with entity configuration and state but nothing seems to work.
I believe that this problem has already been solved by someone.
Please share the solution or your thoughts about.

Answer (score 7):

This happens because for primary keys of type int (and some others) EF Core by default configures the database to generate the corresponding id on insert. Therefore the database forbids providing an explicit value like -1. If you want to take care of generating ids yourself mark your Id property with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`. Otherwhise, instead of explicitly assing a value to the Id property, let it be the default value (in this case 0) and EF will inserty your entity and update the Id property to match the Id generated by the database when SaveChanges() is called.

Comment: This threw a 'Cannot create a dbset for <TableName> because this type is not included in the model for the context error for me

Comment: @TheWizardOfTN this error has nothing to do with marking the primary key as database generated or not - it simply means that EF does not know the class you are trying to save. Try adding a `DbSet` for that class or adding it to the model though the `Configure` method